# Express mode configuration, issue with loading partials

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

The server find the views in "development" mode but not in "production" mode. Instead of the real views it shows me the 404 view.

For instance, with this route "/login":

- **It work** : with development code **(CASE 1)**, GET views/login.html provide the real login content
- **It doesn't work** : with production code (**CASE 2)**, GET views/login.html provide the content of my 404 view

In order to test in development mode both configurations, I just swith code manually. Here is some of my Express configuration:

```
    // Express Configuration
app.configure('development', function(){
      // CASE 2: PRODUCTION CONFIG TO TEST 
  app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

  /* CASE 1: REAL DEVELOPMENT CONFIG
      app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
      */
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

  // Router needs to be last
    app.use(app.router);
});

// Controllers
var api = require('./lib/controllers/api'),
    controllers = require('./lib/controllers');

// Angular Routes
app.get('/views/*', controllers.partials);
app.get('/*', controllers.index);
```

Here are the architecture which is used in dev mode:

->app

---->scripts

---->views

------>login.html

------>404.html

Here are the architecture in prod mode and the folders used (after "grunt build"):

->public

->views

--->login.html

--->404.html

Comment: Sorry but this looks like a "Solve my production problem" kind of question to me. It is not even related with angularjs.

Comment: misunderstood why the 404 partial is returned. Nothing related to the client routes?

Comment: Client makes a request to load the partial and server cannot find it and returns 404. You can try the same thing by typing the url to the browser.

Comment: yes you are right, so it is 100% an express configuration issue

Comment: Does it at least show you a favicon in non-working mode? Do files have right read permissions? The ones you use in production mode.

Comment: Also try using errorHandler in non-working mode to see the error

Comment: Yes i can access each script files and favicon and the index.html too. errorHandler doesn't show error. Express just show :"GET /views/login.html 304 3ms
" as everything is fine

Comment: You have a different path for the views in dev (__dirname + '/app/views') vs prod (__dirname + '/views')

Comment: @HectorCorrea yes, depending on prod or dev mode, i pick views in different folder